# Can two QProcesses communicate via signals and slots?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to communicate from 1 QProcess to another. So do I need some IPC mechanism or can I do it with signal and slots also.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you please start here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can communicate via signals and slots

> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html